# Get Values from a Nested Array with format

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to extract data from a nested array but i cant come up with a working solution.
The JSON array is:

```
{
  "Body": {
    "stkCallback": {
      "MerchantRequestID": "26452-605723-2",
      "CheckoutRequestID": "ws_CO_23042018105859659",
      "ResultCode": 0,
      "ResultDesc": "The service request is processed successfully.",
      "CallbackMetadata": {
        "Item": [
          {
            "Name": "Amount",
            "Value": 1
          },
          {
            "Name": "MpesaReceiptNumber",
            "Value": "MDN6ZJE4XG"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Balance"
          },
          {
            "Name": "TransactionDate",
            "Value": 20180423105912
          },
          {
            "Name": "PhoneNumber",
            "Value": 254722200121
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my PHP Code to extract, Amount, MpesaReceiptNumber, PhoneNumber, TransactionDate:
I can read the first section using the code below but not the second:

```
$arrContextOptions = array( 'ssl' => array( 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, ), );
$data = @file_get_contents( $url, false, stream_context_create( $arrContextOptions ) );
if ( $data != '' ) {
    $arr = json_decode($data, true);
    echo $string =  $arr['Body']['stkCallback']['MerchantRequestID'];  // Working
    echo $string =  $arr['Body']['stkCallback']['MerchantRequestID']['Item'][0]; //Not Working
}
```

Comment: `MerchantRequestID` is an ID (i.e. string), not an array. but the second line tries to use it as one.

Comment: Why do people mark questions as duplicated but and provide URLs that do not even explain the basics of what is being asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `["item"][0]` is an array and can't be echoed.
You need to echo for example the `["name"]` in `[0]`.

```
echo $arr['Body']['stkCallback']['MerchantRequestID'] . "\n";  // Working

Foreach($arr['Body']['stkCallback']['CallbackMetadata']['Item'] as $subarr){
    Foreach($subarr as $item){
        Echo $item ."\n";
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/AJn9N

Comment: I wanted the value of the Amount, i.e. and not the name Amount. How can i can the values of the other elements upto PhoneNumber","Value":

Comment: You need two nested foreach loops. https://3v4l.org/AJn9N

Answer (score 0):

By linting your JSON with [JsonLint](https://jsonlint.com/)

We see that you tried to access to an array by calling an ID `MerchantRequestID`

You've set the wrong path in your array keys you should try

```
 print_r($arr['Body']['stkCallback']['CallbackMetadata']['Item'][0]);
```

instead of

```
echo $string =  $arr['Body']['stkCallback']['MerchantRequestID']['Item'][0];
```

I use the `print_r` method since you can't `echo` an array

Answer (score 0):

It should be:
`echo $string =  $arr['Body']['stkCallback']['CallbackMetadata']['Item'][0];`